# Empty search string not yielding all documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastica's query builder to create queries for ElasticSearch (version 5.3)

I've around 1600 documents indexed in a particular index and type,

When I perform a search in that index with a empty string in query, I only get around 440 hits,

The generated query is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "",
                    "fields": ["<field_1>^5", "<field_2>^4", "<field_3>^1", "<field_4>^2"],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "aggs": {
        "<agg_name_1>": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "<agg_field_1>"
            }
        },
        "<agg_name_2>": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "<agg_field_2>"
            }
        },
        "<agg_name_3>": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "<agg_field_3>"
            }
        },
        "<agg_name_4>": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "<agg_field_4>"
            }
        },
        "<agg_name_5>": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "<agg_field_5>"
            }
        },
        "<date_agg_name>": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "<agg_field_date_1>",
                "keyed": true,
                "ranges": [{
                    "from": "now\/d",
                    "key": "NOW\/DAY TO *"
                }, {
                    "from": "now-2d\/d",
                    "key": "NOW\/DAY-2DAY TO *"
                }, {
                    "from": "now-7d\/d",
                    "key": "NOW\/DAY-7DAY TO *"
                }, {
                    "from": "now-30d\/d",
                    "key": "NOW\/DAY-30DAY TO *"
                }]
            }
        },
        "<agg_name_integer>": {
            "range": {
                "field": "<agg_field_integer>",
                "keyed": true,
                "ranges": [{
                    "to": 1,
                    "key": "1"
                }, {
                    "to": 2,
                    "key": "2"
                }, {
                    "to": 3,
                    "key": "3"
                }, {
                    "to": 4,
                    "key": "4"
                }, {
                    "to": 5,
                    "key": "5"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that since the query is empty string, it should match all the documents, but why is it only matching a subset of the document? I also tried changing `should` with `must`,  but there was no difference.

Is it because of `multi_match` ? or `fuzziness` ? or `fields` ?

P. S. The actual name of fields are changed and replaced with placeholder.

Comment: What ES version?

Comment: @AndreiStefan 5.3 , will edit and add to question.

Comment: I tested this and I get no documents back. How are you sending the query to ES?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm using `ruflin/elastica` to build the query and send the query. Would it help if I put that code in the question?

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Same with me..

Comment: @cipher then it seems the query you are building is not the one you thought you are

Comment: @Richa @AndreiStefan , I just tested the query using postman, and searching on `elastichost:9200/index/type/_search` endpoint, and it does return a subset of results

Comment: What http method did you use?

Comment: used POST, because of postman, I'll be happy to `curl` and send a GET request, give me a moment

Comment: Yeah, try with GET.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes, Get also yields same result. 
`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/job/documents/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpjaGFuZ2VtZQ==' --data '@./testdata' | head
` returned output along the lines of `"hits" : { "total" : 428 ... `

Comment: What's the content of `testdata`?

Comment: the query i posted above, but the field names are different.  // @AndreiStefan would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: Try taking out the query from the json file and use it directly in the `curl` call.

Comment: @AndreiStefan sorry but didn't get that completely. How do you mean? send the json as an string without using file? or use get parameters to send query?

Comment: Not using a `@filename` in `curl` but sending the text as string.

Comment: @AndreiStefan

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/job/documents/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpjaGFuZ2VtZQ==' -d'
{
    "query": { "bool" : { "should" : [{ "multi_match" : { "query":"", "fields": ["job_titleText^5", "job_shortDescription^4", "job_companyText^1", "job_keywords^2"],
"fuzziness": "AUTO" } }] } }, "from": 0, "size":20 }' | head` also gets 428 hits

Comment: What do you get if you run `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it says `missing authentication token` like it should? and if I pass the auth header, it says the following: `{
  "name" : "P19-I28",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "EFzc5L0pQuCKEazAGHlb5A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "3068195",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-24T16:15:59.481Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
`

Comment: I was testing with 5.3.0 so far. But now I tried with 5.3.2 and I get same (0 results) output.

Comment: @AndreiStefan but the question is how do i get all results?

Answer (score 0):

If the query field is empty you can use match_all query

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html

multi match does not work with empty keywords as far as i have noticed.